# Looking for standard terminology for a pattern of composition

Tags: functions, terminology, inverse

Given the functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to B$, a common, useful strategy is to define a new function $h\colon A\to A$ as the composition $f^{-1}\circ g\circ f$.

There seem to be many applications and conceptually similar maneuvers, ranging from the "Schwarzian transform" (used in programming to sort arbitrary data without redundant key computation) to Fourier convolution ($f * g = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{f\}\cdot \mathcal{F}\{g\}\}$).

Is there a standard name for this general pattern of composition?

(One comment suggested this was a duplication of another question, which asked what to call the constituent parts of a composition. This is not that. I'm asking about a name for the specific pattern $h = f^{-1}\circ g\circ f$.)

Comment: It's almost conjugation. And can probably be interpreted as such with minor adjustments to the setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the functions that make composite functions called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847640/what-are-the-functions-that-make-composite-functions-called)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please see last paragraph, added for distinction.