# What are the functions that make composite functions called?

Tags: terminology

What do you call the functions that make a composite function.

Example : $e^{\sin x} $ is made up of $\sin x$ in the argument of $e^x$

So what are $\sin x$ and $e^x$ called here in this context? Basic functions or something?

(Please don't tell me the former is trig and latter is exponential function, I know that, but that's not what I'm asking here, please try to understand)

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Elementary functions

Comment: I don't think there's a standard word for these. In keeping with *summands* for the terms of a sum, I suppose I would call these *components*.

Comment: Nomenclature isn't important in mathematics. It's about the the methodology that one uses to clarify a problem.

Comment: This gives rise to the term "chain rule" in calculus (at least I think it does) because you link together functions one after the other in a chain. But I don't think the vocabulary stretches that far. We just call it the chain rule, and kids have to figure out on their own why. That being said, I've used the terms "inner function" and "outer function". It works nicely when there are only two ($\sin x$ would be the inner and $e^x$ the outer).

Comment: @Adam https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function I don't think Elementary functions mean what you think it means, check that link out. And see the examples.

Comment: @AnonymousI Nomenclature is important in math if you want to communicate with other people.

Comment: And why would someone downvote this question again? It's a legit doubt? Please mention the reason too.

Comment: @Adam I think he is seeking a term like "summand" and "multiplicand", but for function composition. So in $a+b$, $a$ and $b$ are summands. In $a\circ b$ what do we call them?

Comment: I'm not aware of any terminology that answers your question. Nonetheless, in the context of teaching the chain rule in a calculus class, I will introduce variables and terminology like this: $y = \sin(x)$, $z = e^y$, so $z = \sin(x)$. I explain carefully which variables depend on which, and I refer to $x$ as the independent variable, $z$ the dependent variable, and $y$ the intermediate variable.

Comment: @AnonymousI: are you serious ?

Answer (score 4):

To short circuit the comments back and forth I'll provide a (community wiki) answer.

I know of no established terminology for this. If you need one for something you are writing I think "components" would be appropriate. The "compo" prefix nicely suggests "composition". Be sure to define that term for your readers, and note that the order in which you compose matters.

-- Ethan Bolker

You could also (if you were writing an article discussing this extensively, and had to use the words over and over) invent your own words, in analogy with "summand" or "multiplicand"; because of the asymmetry of the relation, I'd aim for an analogy with division or subtraction: you might, for instance, call the outer function the "composer" and the inner the "composand". Words like this are not (as far as I know) in common use, perhaps because the need for them hasn't arisen as often as those for the elementary arithmetic operations.

-- John Hughes

Comment: @JohnHughes nice.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but maybe the term you want is [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/elementary_function)?

Or if, as Thomas Andrews suggested, what you want is analogous to the term "factors" for the factors $a,b,c$ in a product $a\cdot b\cdot c$, I think the word you want is "component". The components in your expression have been *composed* into a larger express, so "component"is just right.

In some contexts, [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/combinatory_logic) in particular, the function $g(x)$ in $f(g(x))$ is commonly called the *applicand* of $f$, but the context you're asking about is so far removed from this that "applicand" might just confuse people.  Or maybe not! But if there's a corresponding term for the $f$ part of $f(g(x))$ I can't think what it is.